# How can I un-link my current Microsoft account that is tagged to my Windows activation license and link it to a new Microsoft account?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I would like to change the email address that the activation key is linked to, so that when I reformat the computer, I can log in to my new account and the computer can be activated. Based on research, there does not seem to be any resources online that teaches how to do so, only how to do the initial linking for the very first Microsoft account.

Answer (score 1):

You don't make a new account & try to move your entitlements to it, you change the email address associated with the original account.

From Microsoft Support - [Change the email address or phone number for your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12407/microsoft-account-change-email-phone-number)

> **I want to use a different email address or phone number to sign in**
>
> You can use any email address or phone number you have listed as a
>   username to sign in to your Microsoft account. If you want to sign in
>   with a specific one or change the one you're signing in with, here's
>   how:
>
> 1. Sign in to [Manage how you sign in to Microsoft](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=529489) with your Microsoft account. If you’re having issues signing in to your
>      Microsoft account, go to [Microsoft account help](https://support.microsoft.com/hub/4294457#sign-in-issues).
>
> `Note You may be prompted to enter your Microsoft account password, or
>   to enter a code sent to the email address or phone number listed in
>   your account's security information. By providing this info to us, we
>   know the request is coming from you.`
>
> 2. If you want to use an existing email address or phone number, go to step 6. If you're adding a new email address or phone number, go to
>      step 3.
> 3. If you selected Add a phone number, go to step 5. If you selected Add email, choose whether to add:
>      a. A new email address. Select Create a new email address and add it as an alias, and then follow the instructions.
>      b. A non-Microsoft email address (such as an @gmail.com or @yahoo.com email address).  Select Add an existing email address as a Microsoft
>      account alias, and then select Add alias.
> 4. ​​​​​​After you've added the email address, you'll be asked to verify that you're the account owner:
>      a. Select Verify next to the new alias. A message is sent to the account for verification.
>      b. After you receive the message, select the included link to confirm that you own the account.
> 5. If you selected Add a phone number, follow these steps:
>      a. Select your country from the list.
>      b. Enter the phone number you
>      want to use, and then select Next.
>      c. When you add a new phone
>      number, we'll send a text message to that number to verify it. Enter
>      the code in the text message, and then select Next.
> 6. Under Sign-in preferences, select Change sign-in preferences.
> 7. Either select the check boxes next to the aliases that you want to use to sign in or clear the check boxes for the aliases that you don’t
>      want to use to sign in, and then select Save.

Answer (score -1):

The procedure is described in the Microsoft article
[How to change the email address associated with your Microsoft account](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/change-email-sign-in-for-microsoft-account).

The detailed description can be found in the article.
In short, you need to add the new email which is called "alias",
then designate it as the primary so the current primary turns into an alias.
Finally, delete the new alias which was initially your old email.

Comment: Why was I downvoted and the data from my link copied into the other answer?